# When grepping a file, grep is returning true instead of the lines, why?

Tags: grep

I am running a grep on a file that is about 13G in size. It is returning

```
Binary file file.xml matches
```

I was not expecting this, I thought it would return each line with my string so that I could run the following,

```
grep "searchString" ./file.xml | wc -l
```

and return a count of all the occurrences of my searchString in my large file.

Comment: Out of interest, what does `file file.xml` return?

Comment: file.xml: XML document text

Comment: nit: This finds the number of lines having searchString, not the number of instances ("Hi, I'm searchString searchString searchString, how are you?") counts as one hit, not three.

Comment: Also, might return "1" if this is a compact (i.e. not prettyprint, <xsl:output indent="no" />) file... which might also explain why it gets picked up as binary, no evident record breaks found within the first chunk of the file. I've been hosed on this trying to grep things in WordML files, ended up using `xmllint --format infile.xml > infile.xml-formatted` to get something usable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like grep thinks your XML file is binary rather than text.

If you want to force grep to treat your file as text regardless of the contents, you can use its `--text` switch (assuming GNU grep), like so:

```
grep --text "searchString" ./file.xml | wc -l
```

Note that if all you want is to count matches, it's probably better to use `grep --count` rather than piping through `wc -l`, saving you a pipe and process invocation.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling `grep --count` will also return number of lines. From man: `-c, --count
Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines for  each  input  file.`

Comment: @rush Argh, you're right. Sorry, never mind that then.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are some uncommon symbols in the beginning of your file and `grep` detects it as binary. You can try `--binary-files=text` option.

```
grep --binary-files=text "searchString" file.xml | wc -l
```

From man page:

```
   --binary-files=TYPE
          If the first few bytes of a file indicate that the file contains
          binary  data, assume that the file is of type TYPE.  By default,
          TYPE is binary, and grep  normally  outputs  either  a  one-line
          message  saying  that  a  binary  file matches, or no message if
          there is no match.  If TYPE is without-match, grep assumes  that
          a  binary  file  does  not  match;  this is equivalent to the -I
          option.  If TYPE is text, grep processes a binary file as if  it
          were  text;  this is equivalent to the -a option.  Warning: grep
          --binary-files=text might output binary garbage, which can  have
          nasty  side  effects  if  the  output  is  a terminal and if the
          terminal driver interprets some of it as commands.
```

Comment: Or near-equivalently `grep -a -c 'searchString' file.xml` and avoid the superfluous `wc -l`.

Comment: Just DOS carriage returns are enough to turn a file into "binary".

Comment: @tripleee Not to be a nit, but I thought [I already said that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82340/2465) :)

Comment: @MikaelKjörling: After I posted my comment, yes. Yours is now the better answer so you got my vote.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like you have a mistake when using `./file.xml`. If you try:

```
grep "searchString" file.xml | wc -l
```

Does it have any problems?

Comment: `file.xml` and `./file.xml` refer to exactly the same file, with the additional safety net that in the latter case, the real name of `file.xml` can safely begin with e.g. `-`.

Comment: not going to vote down but above comment is right no difference between what you have and what I tried.